# Why is my SAP B1 stored procedure not working for UDF

Tags: sapb1

I created a UDF RetReas (Return Reason) for Sales AR > Return. The UDF is applied to the rows. I need to block the adding of drafts if the UDF is blank. My code on the stored procedure, SBO_SP_TransactionNotification is not working. The draft for Return is still being added even if the UDF is blank. Here is the code

```
IF (@object_type ='112' AND @transaction_type IN ('A','U'))  
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @RetReason nvarchar(30)

        SELECT  @LineNum = b.VisOrder+1, @ObjType = CAST(A.ObjType as varchar(32)), @RetReason = COALESCE(B.U_RetReas,'')
        FROM ODRF A  INNER JOIN DRF1 B ON A.DocEntry = B.DocEntry
        WHERE A.DocEntry = @list_of_cols_val_tab_del and ISNULL(A.WddStatus,'-') <> '-'  

        IF (@ObjType = '16')
            IF ( @RetReason = '')
                BEGIN
                    SET  @error =  -100018
                    SET  @error_message=N'Return reason is required!'
                END
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

when i remove this it is working on my local

```
and ISNULL(A.WddStatus,'-') <> '-'
```

is this document related to an Authorization Process?

Comment: Please leave follow-up info as a comment